# Please explain how this code is executing

Tags: java

I have recently started writing java code to send emails. I had come across a piece of code from website [Mkyong](https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/).

```
 Session session = Session.getInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
         return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
     }
 });
```

Here while calling Session.getInstance he is passing a couple pf parameters. I do not understand what is happening after creating an Authenticator object and how he is calling the getPasswordAuthentication() method. Please let me know where I could read about this kind of programming.

Thanks

Comment: You can read everything on oracle's web-site about that methods. For example if you want how this Authenticator class is working,just take a look at this link http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Authenticator.html

Comment: I had gone through the API for Authenticator class but still not able to figure it out. Could you please give a simpler explanation.

Comment: Is it the [Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) that you don't understand?

Comment: Yes regarding Anonymous classes. I had never bothered to look into it. I am looking into it right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

session have a method of setPasswordAuthentication,  from api you know that Called when password authentication is needed